# Удалить элемент из JSON ARRAY Mysql

Tags: mysql, json

Есть таблица channels в которой есть колонка users формата json

```
[
    {
        "date": "2019-04-14",
        "user": 630184594
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-04-14",
        "user": 345344594
    }
]
```

Надо удалить элемент в котором user = 630184594

Пробую так

```
SELECT JSON_REMOVE(users,'$.user') = "630184594" AS 'Result' FROM channels
```

Но элемент не удаляется

Comment: Это новый формат в mysql, к примеру получаю я данные вот так SELECT * FROM channels WHERE currentAmount < finalAmount AND JSON_CONTAINS(`users`, JSON_OBJECT('user', %s))

Comment: ну например тут https://database.guide/json_remove-remove-data-from-a-json-document-in-mysql/ . Слека не понимаю вопроса

Comment: [посмотрите суда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956776/mysql-json-remove-json-array)

Comment: Да там есть решение в котором уже известно индекс элемента, но я не знаю его индекс

Comment: Ошибки есть какие-то? Возможно не получится без индекса, но не уверен.

Comment: SELECT JSON_REMOVE(users,'$.user') = "630184594" AS 'Result' FROM channels

Этот запрос вернет мне индекс

А этот удалит нужный мне элемент, но я не знаю как скомбинировать их 
UPDATE channels
SET users = JSON_REMOVE(users, '$[index]') WHERE channelName = 'chrtr'

Comment: а прямо в индекс прописать запрос не вариант? (привет производительности)

Comment: Я по факту так и сделал, но выглядит очень плохо, думаю есть вариант лучше, но не знаю как его реализовать